# Modbus Communication Issue: "Unable to read data from the transport connection"

Tags: c#

I am working on a project that involves communicating with a Modbus device using C# and the NModbus library. However, I've encountered an issue where I am unable to read data from the Modbus device, and I'm receiving the following error message:

```
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

I've included a snippet of my C# code below, and the issue seems to occur at the line where I'm attempting to read holding registers from the Modbus device.
so far i have found the problem in this line

```
values = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(ID, startAddress, numInputs);
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using NModbus;
using NModbus.Utility;

namespace Modbus_Data_Aggregator
{
    class ModbusTCPDevice : IModbusDevice
    {
        private string _deviceIp;
        private ushort _port;
        private byte _deviceId;
        public ModbusByteOrder ModbusByteOrder { get; set; }

        public ModbusTCPDevice(string deviceIp, ushort port, byte deviceId, ModbusByteOrder modbusByteOrder)
        {
            IP = deviceIp;
            Port = port;
            ID = deviceId;
            ModbusByteOrder = modbusByteOrder;
        }

        public string IP
        {
            get { return _deviceIp; }
            set
            {
                bool validIp = IsValidIPAddress(value);
                if (validIp)
                {
                    _deviceIp = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException($"{value} is not a valid IPV4 Address");
                }
            }
        }

        public ushort Port
        {
            get { return _port; }
            set { _port = value; }
        }

        public byte ID
        {
            get { return _deviceId; }
            set { _deviceId = value; }
        }

        public static bool IsValidIPAddress(string _ipaddress)
        {
            IPAddress ip;
            bool ValidateIP = IPAddress.TryParse(_ipaddress, out ip);
            return ValidateIP;
        }

        public bool[] ReadBitValuesFromSlave(Tag tag)
        {
            using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(IP, Port))
            {
                var factory = new ModbusFactory();
                IModbusMaster master = factory.CreateMaster(client);

                ushort startAddress = tag.StartAddress;
                ushort numInputs = tag.NumInputs;
                bool[] bits = new bool[numInputs];

                if (tag.Register == ModbusDataType.DiscretInputs)
                {
                    bits = master.ReadInputs(ID, startAddress, numInputs);
                }
                else if (tag.Register == ModbusDataType.Coils)
                {
                    bits = master.ReadCoils(ID, startAddress, numInputs);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException("This Data type does not Support Reading bit value.");
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < numInputs; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{tag.Name} register {(startAddress + i)}={(bits[i] ? 1 : 0)}");
                }

                return bits;
            }
        }

        // Other methods...

        public void UpdateTagsValueInBulk(List<Tag> tags)
        {
            Tuple<ushort, ushort> minMaxAddrs = GetMinMaxAddrs(tags);
            ushort minAddr = minMaxAddrs.Item1;
            ushort maxAddr = minMaxAddrs.Item2;

            using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(IP, Port))
            {
                var factory = new ModbusFactory();
                IModbusMaster master = factory.CreateMaster(client);

                ushort startAddress = minAddr;
                ushort numInputs = (ushort)(maxAddr - minAddr + 1);
                ushort[] values = new ushort[numInputs];

                try
                {
                    values = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(ID, startAddress, numInputs);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error reading holding registers: {ex.Message}");
                    // Handle the exception as needed
                }

                foreach (Tag tag in tags)
                {
                    var valueIndex = tag.StartAddress - minAddr;
                    var tag_values = values.Skip(valueIndex).Take(tag.NumInputs).ToArray();
                    Double? value = null;

                    if (tag.NumInputs == 2 && this.ModbusByteOrder == ModbusByteOrder.BigEndian)
                    {
                        value = (Double?)ModbusUtility.GetSingle(tag_values[0], tag_values[1]);
                    }
                    else if (tag.NumInputs == 2 && this.ModbusByteOrder == ModbusByteOrder.LittleEndian)
                    {
                        value = (Double?)ModbusUtility.GetSingle(tag_values[1], tag_values[0]);
                    }
                    else if (tag.NumInputs == 4 && this.ModbusByteOrder == ModbusByteOrder.BigEndian)
                    {
                        value = (Double?)ModbusUtility.Get
``
```